# Why can't I generate new angular project with Angular-CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've installed Angular-CLI with npm and there were no problems. Then I tried to generate a new project by running the command:

`ng new my-app`

After some time I've got information than app has been successfuly generated so everything seems to be ok. But de facto no files has been created. The folder is empty.

What is interesting, when I run again the command to create my-app there is a warning:

`Directory 'my-app' already exists.`

I have no idea where is the problem. I don't see any created files in that folder, in folder above and in general everywhere.

*os: win32 x64

node: 7.6.0

npm: 4.2.0

@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.32.3*

Comment: Do you use angular-cli or new repo @angular/cli ? What is the version number of it ? Did you try the "ng init" command ?

Comment: I use `@angular/cli: 1.0.0-beta.32.3`. "ng init" triggers error `The specified command init is invalid.`

Comment: Sorry, the "ng init" doesn't seem to exist anymore."ng new my-app" work for me for the same angular/cli version. So can you try to reinstall it ? "npm uninstall -g @angular/cli" + "npm cache clean" + "npm install -g @angular/cli". Don't forget to execute this commands as admin.

Comment: Unfortunately reinstallation didn't help at all

Comment: Did you try to do it directly on c:\ to be sure they are not path problems ? (Like space on user name)

Comment: check your nodejs  path is correct  at system variables. you can remove the nodejs path and reinstall node

Comment: @Gilsdav I've created a new project directly on c:\ and it works. Thank you for a hint. Howewer my previous path was `C:\Users\abc\Desktop\WebDeveloper\test` and I don't know what is wrong with it.